# Linear-time logspace encodable error correcting code with constant

Tags: co.combinatorics, computer-science, coding-theory

Is there a binary code with (quasi)constant rate, constant relative distance, and an encoder that takes (quasi)linear time and logspace simultaneously? Note that there are no constraints on decodability - really, I just want a fast and logspace deterministic way to map input strings so that they far from each other. I'd also be okay with all the (quasi) parts being replaced with blowup that is less than $n^{\epsilon}$ for every $\epsilon< 0$.

Two codes I found that are close but not quite are:

- [Spielman](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/PAPERS/linearTimeIT.pdf)'s codes don't quite work out-of-the-box cause, while they nominally have logspace and linear time encoding and decoding with constant rate/distance, it seemed like they have superlinear construction time, and I think I need an algorithm that, given a message, outputs a codeword in linear time including any preprocessing.
- I don't think the code described in [Babai et al.](https://lance.fortnow.com/papers/files/check.pdf) works because I don't think encoding is naively in logspace.

Comment: Binary alphabet, or?

Comment: Yes, sorry - edited to make this clear

Comment: To the best of my understanding, polar codes have sublinear time complexity but memory requirement is much larger than logspace, probably also just sublinear but not better. so they would be ruled out